# dowloading a pdf rendered by rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

i redered a pdf file from an rmd template and i want to let the user to download it
i get the download it compltely with internet download manager but i cant with with the browsers
the browser tries to download the name-of-the-button.txt Couldn't download - No file

here is the code
ui

```
      actionButton("submitBtn", "Soumettre", 
                   style = "color: white; background-color: #662424; border-color: #662424",
                   title = "Soumettre!",
                   onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('btnClicked', true);"),
      conditionalPanel( condition = "input.submitBtn > 0" ,
                        downloadButton("download", "download PDF Report")
      )
```

server

```
    observeEvent(input$submitBtn, {
      
      output_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
      # Add the code to render the R Markdown report
      rmarkdown::render(
        "dynamic_report_template.Rmd",
        output_file = output_file,
        params = list(
          rmse_rr_report = rmse_rr,
          biais_rr_report = biais_rr,          
          
        ),
        output_format = "pdf_document"
      )
      
      
      output$download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          "dynamic_report_output.pdf"
        },
        content = function(file) {
          file.copy(output_file, file)
        },
        contentType = "application/pdf"
      )
      
      output$report_generation_status <- renderText({
        "PDF report has been generated."
      })
    })
```

Comment: You have to save the file in the www folder of your shiny app